# stackpanel containing button does not fire command wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, icommand

I have a stackpanel that contains many elements including buttons. I am not able to fire a method through ICommands. It works through adding an event handler in the code behind for the Button.Click event. Since, I am following a MVVM pattern, I want to fire a command. Also, this stackpanel is a datatemplate for my listviewitem.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="True">
            <Button Cursor="Hand" Command="{Binding MoveImageUp}">
               <Button.Background>
                   <ImageBrush ImageSource="..."/>                                      
               </Button.Background>
            </Button>
            <Grid>
                 <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
                 <TextBlock Height="20" Width="20" Text="{Binding Path=Order}" Opacity="0.8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
             </Grid>
             <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have tried setting `IsHitTestVisibile` to `true`, does not work.

Comment: I assume you command is in one level up, so you have to specify correct context for binding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056939/wpf-button-in-listview-can-not-see-command-in-viewmodel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954550/why-does-my-command-binding-for-my-button-not-work

Comment: if it was a problem just close your Q as duplicate (do not remove it)

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Comment: @Foggy Finder : I have one more problem. In the same code above, I am using SelectedItemIndex within the MoveImageUp.Execute(). And I am able to fire the command on let's say 2nd element of the list, although my 0th element was selected. Is there anyway to pass to select the item, on which my MoveImageUp command was fired?

Comment: hm, it seems in your answer, you pass the data of element as commandParameter who fired command

Comment: if something goes wrong feel free come to [WPF SO chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)

Comment: Thanks @Foggy Finder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no DataContext set for the button. Thanks @Foggy Finder

```
<Button Cursor="Hand" Command="{Binding ElementName=ImagesList, Path=DataContext.MoveImageUp}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```